# Reduce all values to one specified

Tags: sorting, python-3.x

So I have a group of lists which looks like:

```
[['Amy,1,"10,10,6"'], ['Bella,3,"4,7,2"'], ['Cendrick,3,"5,1,9"'], ['Fella,2,"3,8,4"'], ['Hussain,1,"9,4,3"'], ['Jamie,2,"1,1,1"'], ['Jack,3,"10,8,0"'], ['Thomas,2,"5,0,5"'], ['Zyra,1,"7,8,7"']]
```

Whereby the number after the name is the student's class number and the following 3 numbers are the 3 scores which that student scored.

I have sorted it from an organised group of lists to this alphabetical one however I am having difficulty with the following:

I want to be able to sort them alphabetically but only for a specific class and the highest score out of the last three values. For example, if I wanted to sort class 2, then the output would be as follows:

```
Fella,8
Jamie,1
Thomas,5
```

As the names have been sorted alphabetically and all students are from class 2. Each students high score has also been placed beside them.

I would really appreciate any help. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the solution, with the way you've your data stored at the moment -- makes processing hard.

```
>>> lst = [['Amy,1,"10,10,6"'], ['Bella,3,"4,7,2"'], ['Cendrick,3,"5,1,9"'],
 ['Fella,2,"3,8,4"'], ['Hussain,1,"9,4,3"'], ['Jamie,2,"1,1,1"'], ['Jack,3,"10,8,0"'], ['Thomas,2,"5,0,5"'], ['Zyra,1,"7,8,7"']]

>>> from itertools import chain
>>> lst_flat = chain.from_iterable(lst)
>>> sorted_lst = sorted(filter(lambda x: x.split(',')[1] == '2', lst_flat))
>>> print map(lambda x: (x.split(',')[0],
              max([int(y) for y in x.split('"')[1].split(',')])), sorted_lst)

[('Fella', 8), ('Jamie', 1), ('Thomas', 5)]
```

You should consider cleaning up the way you've represented your data:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> from itertools import chain

>>> lst_clean = []
>>> for item in chain.from_iterable(lst):
    ... name, cls = item.split(',')[0], item.split(',')[1]
    ... marks = [int(x) for x in item.split('"')[1].split(',')]
    ... lst_clean.append((name, cls, marks))

>>> pprint(lst_clean)

[('Amy', '1', [10, 10, 6]),
('Bella', '3', [4, 7, 2]),
('Cendrick', '3', [5, 1, 9]),
('Fella', '2', [3, 8, 4]),
('Hussain', '1', [9, 4, 3]),
('Jamie', '2', [1, 1, 1]),
('Jack', '3', [10, 8, 0]),
('Thomas', '2', [5, 0, 5]),
('Zyra', '1', [7, 8, 7])]

>>> sorted_lst = sorted([(name, cls, marks) for (name, cls, marks) in lst_clean if cls == '2'])
>>> for name, cls, marks in sorted_lst:
    ... print name, max(marks)

Fella 8
Jamie 1
Thomas 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would work:

```
def transform(inputs, class_number):
  results = []
  for input in inputs:
    input = input[0]
    input_pieces = input.split(',', 2)
    if input_pieces[1] != class_number:
      continue
    scores = input_pieces[2].strip('"').split(',')
    results.append((input_pieces[0], max(scores)))
  return results
```

Also, I strongly recommend you use something to give your data a little more structure than just a comma-separated string. Something like [collections.namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). Then you could have a list of namedtuple's with meaningfully named fields.

Comment: I didn't notice every element was a single string. I edited my solution.

Comment: What did you mean by the "inputs" inside the transform function - should I put the name of the list inside here when I call the function?

Comment: Yes, you pass in the list.

Comment: I keep on getting a syntax error at the return point in the function

Answer (score 1):

Your data structure is way off. It looks like you wanted to hold information about each student in a list, but ended up putting just one comma delimited string with that information in that list. You then ended up with a list of lists, each of which contained one such string.

This is really what you wanted to do:

```
[[Amy, 1, 10,10,6],
 [Bella, 3, 4,7,2],
 [Cendrick, 3, 5,1,9],
 [Fella, 2, 3,8,4],
 [Hussain, 1, 9,4,3],
 [Jamie, 2, 1,1,1],
 [Jack, 3, 10,8,0],
 [Thomas, 2, 5,0,5],
 [Zyra, 1, 7,8,7]
]
```

Here's how you transform what you have, into what you wanted:

```
students = []

for student in myList:  # myList is the list that you already have
    s = []
    name, course, grades = student[0].split(',', 2)
    s.append(name)
    s.append(int(course))
    s.extend([int(i) for i in grades.strip('"').split(',')])
    students.append(s)
```

Once you have this, then you can filter and sort `students` as follows:

```
import operator
classNum = 1  # let's say you want all the students from class number 1
answer = sorted([s for s in students if s[1]==classNum], key=operator.itemgetter(0))

for student in answer:
    name = student[0]
    grade = max(student[2:]))
    print(name, grade)
```

Note that I said that this is what it seems like you wanted to do. In your position, this is what I would do:

```
from collections import namedtuple as ntuple

Student = ntuple('Student', ['name', 'course', 'grades'])
students = []

courseNum = 1
for student in myList:  # myList is the list that you already have
    s = Student
    name, course, grades = student[0].split(',', 2)
    course = int(course)
    if course != courseNum: continue
    grades = [int(i) for i in grades.strip('"').split(',')]
    students.append(Student(name, course, grades))

students.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('name'))
for student in students:
    print(student.name, max(student.grades))
```

Comment: I am getting the same error either way. It says that there are too many values to unpack as it expects 3 at the name, course, grades = student[0]...

Comment: @Hussain: Sorry about that. I missed a subtle bug in there. Try it now

Comment: @Hussain: please mark an accepted answer so that other users know that your question has been answered

Comment: ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack, I got the same error again, and it occurred in the same position - name, course, grades = student[0]... Sorry to bother you, but could you solve this problem and explain to me what it means when I get this "value unpack" error. TIA.

Comment: @Hussain: You mentioned that this solution worked for you before. I therefore think that something has changed in your input. I would recommend making a fresh post with your inputs and the code that is giving you trouble